# Php variable in quotes

Tags: php, var

I have a php variable

`$objOrdd['delivery_address']`

I want to send its value closed in quotes, i.e string. How can I do that?

I have tried `"{$objOrdd['delivery_address']}"` and  `". $objOrdd['delivery_address'] ."` but it doesn't work!

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Error? Warning? Nothing appears?

Comment: Vote to close. A simple string concatenation google search. Unclear inputs/outputs. Use of "Doesn't work".

Comment: You need to provide a bit more context. Just saying you need quotes somewhere, and providing syntax variations without surrounding code (print, echo, what?) and expected output or usage will only lead to guessed answers.

Comment: I don't think a close is neded, it is obviously he doesn't know so much about coding, it is perfectly understandable that he wants to convert `foo => 'foo'` inside a PHP variable

Comment: @user1381537 If the question doesn't help anyone else it doesn't belong here. There's much better questions for string concatenation, json encoding, or whatever OP is actually trying to accomplish here. Understandable? certainly. Appropriate for SO? No.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways of how to **[interpolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation)** / **[concatenate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)** variables in [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single):

```
// the test
$arr['fox'] = "fox jumps over the ";

// ----------------------

// double quotes: different ways
$str = "The quick brown ".$arr['fox']."lazy dog"; // concat
echo $str."<br>";
# output: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

$str = "The quick brown {$arr['fox']}lazy dog";  // interp.
echo $str."<br>";
# output: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

$str = "The quick brown ${arr['fox']}lazy dog";  // interp.
echo $str."<br>";
# output: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

// ----------------------

// for single quotes concat
$str = 'The quick brown '.$arr['fox'].'lazy dog';
echo $str."<br>";
# output: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

// ----------------------

// or even use sprintf
$str = sprintf('The quick brown %slazy dog', $arr['fox']);
echo $str."<br>";
# output: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Sure there are more than these. I prefer concatenation, whenever possible.

Comment: +1 textbook answer, where did you get it

Comment: @Shanimal Appreciate it :) The quick brown fox [is famous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog).

Answer (score 1):

Suposse `$objOrdd['delivery_address'] = "foo"`

Doing

```
$myVariable = "'" . $objOrdd['delivery_address'] . "'"
```

if you do `echo $myVariable` it will output `'foo'`

You can replace ' char with { or whatever you want...

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this:

```
$var = "'".$objOrdd['delivery_address']."'";
```

Or

```
$var = '"'.$objOrdd['delivery_address'].'"';
```

Comment: format your code!! :D use ` character between code or click on the format menu

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not looking for [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json-encode)`($objOrdd['delivery_address'])`?

Answer (score 0):

addslashes — Quote string with slashes

```
   // Outputs: Is your name O\'reilly?
   echo addslashes($str);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use typecast to send data as string. eg :  $myText = (string)$myVar;

   checkout : [Php variable in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21027751/php-variable-in-quotes)
2. If you want to add quotes to the variable then you need to concatenate it.